# Highcharts determine if data point is outside polygon

Tags: jquery, highcharts, polygon

I am using Highcharts to draw a polygon and determine whether a data point occurs within the polygon or outside the polygon. Below is an example chart:
[image]

The current location is outside the polygon, so I need to perform some other operations based on that location. Short of creating an array of every single polygon datapoint, I wonder if there was a better way to determine this.

Comment: Highcharts lib doesn't provide collision detection for polygon and point. I think this is general problem for [PIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon).

Comment: I was afraid of that. I perused the documentation and couldn't find anything. Thanks for the confirmation.